# How to get a certain index of an item after using product

Tags: python

So this is what I have so far:

```
def createCombo(self):
    usedAtoms = {'C':(0,101),'H':(0,201),'O':(0,4),'N':(0,4),'S':(0,4)}

    MolecularFormula.combinations(self, usedAtoms)

def combinations(self,dicts):

    product = [x for x in itertools.product(*[range(*x) for x in dicts.values()])]
    print product
    ##print [dict(zip(dicts.keys(), p)) for p in product],
```

it ends up printing something out like this:

```
 [(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 3), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 0, 1, 3), (0, 0, 0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0, 2, 1)
```

which is what I want it to print out, but how would I go about grabbing a certain index of an individual one in one of these products?

so like if I wanted to grab the 3 from this: (0, 0, 0, 0, 3)

?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: product = [(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 0, 0, 2), (0, 0, 0,
   ...:  0, 3), (0, 0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1, 2), (0, 0, 0, 1,
   ...:  3), (0, 0, 0, 2, 0), (0, 0, 0, 2, 1)]

In [2]: product[3][4]  # get the fifth value of the fourth element of 'product'
Out[2]: 3
```